# Extracting a single unique character from a pattern in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, stringr

I have a data frame of unique character vectors that are all very similar to a distinct pattern, but with small deviations in each. I'm hoping to find a way to identify what the deviation is in each string. Here is what I have tried:

```
library(stringr)

#The strings are concatenated in my code, I separated them for easier use

KeyPattern <- c('abcd'
uniqchars <- function(x) unique(strsplit(x, "")[[1]]) 
KayPattern <- uniqchars(KeyPattern)

> KeyPattern
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

SampleString <- c('a', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'd')



str_detect(SampleString, KeyPattern)

[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

As you can see, it recognizes the 'z' character, and correctly returns FALSE, and from there the pattern is completely off. I also considered trying:

```
word(string, start = 1L, end = start, sep = fixed(" "))
```

but this requires a pre-existing knowledge of where the deviations are (start = ..., end = ...) and it will be different in every row of the data frame.

Ultimately I want to have a data frame with one column of unique string, a column of distinct deviations (mismatches in the pattern), and it's location in the string.

Goal Sample Table:

| String | Deviation from Key | Deviation start location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'a' 'b' 'c' 'z' 'd' | z | 4 |
| 'a' 'b' 'a' 'c' 'd' | a | 3 |

Current concatenated data frame:

```
1                                  ASGGGGSAASHLIALQLRLIGDAFDGGGGSGGGGSG
2                        ASLTVDVGNVTYHFNNPITVLVFAILVALELGGTVHVHGNRIHVEG
3                        ASLTVHVGDLTYHFENPQLVKLVAEIWARALNLTIEIRGNEIHVEG
4                        ASNELVELVVEILYRMCVDPDQIKKILKRRGVSDEEVKRAIDKAIG
5 ASNMNMLEALQQRLQFYFGVVSRAALENNSGKARRFGRIVKQYEDAIKLYKAGKPVPYDELPVPPGFGG
6 ASNTIMLEALQQRLQFYFGVVSRAALENNSGKARRFGRIVKQYEDAIKLYKAGKPVPYDELPVPPGFGG

#CurrentKey
[1] "ASSTNMLEALQQRLQFYFGVVSRALENNSGKARRFGRIVKQYEDAIKLYKAGKPVPYDELPVPPGFGG"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to maximize the matching of the two vectors?

Comment: Try „which(SampleString %in% KeyString)“

Comment: @deschen This is somewhat helpful as it does return the matching letters, however my actual strings are much longer and may contain characters found in the patter, but in a different place within the pattern ,,,example <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd')''' Apologies for not giving a proper example before.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @user2974951 Apologies if I am misunderstanding you, but essentially, yes. I would ultimately like to return a column for each row of unique vectors with the distinct letter deviation and it's location in the string.

Comment: @RonakShah see above. I will amend my question to elaborate.

Comment: @TaylorBeauvais, can you please include dput instead of giving this html table so that it can be clear whether your column is a list column or concatenated string?

Comment: Have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: @AnilGoyal My data is currently concatenated but I separated it in my code for easier use. I updated these details in my question and amended it to include an exact example from my data. Thanks for your suggested clarification !

Comment: @TaylorBeauvais, I just saw your dput.  Please also provide a `pattern` to check with?

Comment: @Christoph Definitely very much related to the epistemology of my question! Cool that this problem/analysis has an exact name!

Comment: @AnilGoyal just updated with the actual KeyPattern (denoted as "CurrentKey" in the question) I am looking for .

Comment: @TaylorBeauvais, so in this case all your outputs will be `3`?

Answer (score 2):

see if this what you want?

```r
df <- structure(list(STRINGS = list(c("a", "b", "c", "z", "d"), c("a", 
                                                                  "b", "a", "c", "d"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                             -2L))

df
#>         STRINGS
#> 1 a, b, c, z, d
#> 2 a, b, a, c, d

pattern <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(deviation = map_chr(STRINGS, ~  {x <- cumsum(.x[seq_along(pattern)] != pattern); .x[which(x >0)[1]]}),
         deviation_start_loc = map_int(STRINGS, ~  {x <- cumsum(.x[seq_along(pattern)] != pattern); which(x > 0)[1]}))

#>         STRINGS deviation deviation_start_loc
#> 1 a, b, c, z, d         z                   4
#> 2 a, b, a, c, d         a                   3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is very good. This largely answers my question. I am now trying to adapt it to find multiple deviations. Any suggestions? 

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad that it helped.  In my opinion you have to split your concatenated strings before matching.  use `str_split` or similar function for that.  For matching unequal number of strings extract `min` of `nchar` of both strings to be matched and pattern.  I think that will largely do your part

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

First, define a recursive function:

```
find_deviation <- function(string, key, position = 1) {
  stopifnot(is.character(string), is.character(key))
  if (min(length(key), length(string)) == 0)
    return(c(deviation = NA, position = NA))
  if (string[1] != key[1])
    return(c(deviation = string[1], position = position))
  find_deviation(string[-1], key[-1], position + 1)
}
```

Then, use it to generate the desired result:

```
dplyr::bind_cols(
  purrr::map_dfr(SampleString, ~ c(String = paste(.x, collapse = ","))),
  purrr::map_dfr(SampleString, ~ find_deviation(.x, KeyPattern))
)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  String    deviation position
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   
1 a,b,z,c,d z         3       
2 a,b,a,c,d a         3
```

Data used:

```
KeyPattern <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
SampleString <- list(c('a', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'd'), c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'))
```

Comment: This is very good. This largely answers my question. I am now trying to adapt it to find multiple deviations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the deviation an additional character or a replacement? In your example it was additional characters, but your new data looks like your are looking at replacements.

Comment: The trouble is, sometimes it could be either. In some rows it's an additional character, sometimes it is a replacement, sometimes it could be a deletion. I recognize this is pretty tricky, and a bit beyond the scope of my question. Your answer has certainly helped me start to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using aphid library and sequence alignment, the character vectors are combined into a list, the first element being the key pattern vector.

```
library(aphid)

KeyPattern <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
SampleString1 <- c('a', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'd')
SampleString2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'z', 'd')
SampleString3 <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd')

sequences=list(KeyPattern,SampleString1,SampleString2,SampleString3)

do.call(rbind,
  sapply(2:length(sequences),function(x){
    glo=align(sequences[c(1,x)],type="global",k=1)
    tmp=glo[1,]!=glo[2,]
    data.frame(
      "String"=paste0(sequences[[x]],collapse=" "),
      "Deviation from Key"=glo[2,tmp],
      "Deviation start location"=which(tmp)
    )
  },simplify=F)
)

     String Deviation.from.Key Deviation.start.location
1 a b z c d                  z                        3
2 a b c z d                  z                        4
3 a b a c d                  a                        3
```